# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ":"

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to migrate an existing API that used APNs to send and receive messages to be compatible with the new APNs Provider API.

The following script worked for sending test notifications to my testing device before Apple stopped supporting the legacy binary protocol.

```
//simplepush.php

<?php

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'EXAMPLETOKEN';
// Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hello!';
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

[Sending Notification Requests to APNs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns?language=objc) states that the `:method` and `:path` header fields are required for a connection to APNs.

[image]

I've copied the code from the link to the original test script.

```
<?php
HEADERS
- END_STREAM
+ END_HEADERS
:method = POST
:scheme = https
:path = /3/device/EXAMPLETOKEN
host = api.sandbox.push.apple.com
apns-id = eabeae54-14a8-11e5-b60b-1697f925ec7b
apns-push-type = alert
apns-expiration = 0
apns-priority = 10
DATA
+ END_STREAM
{ "aps" : { "alert" : "Hello" } }
// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = 'EXAMPLETOKEN';          // Put your private key's passphrase here:
$passphrase = 'pushchat';
// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Hello!';
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////.   /////////////
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
'ssl://api.sandbox.push.apple.com:443', $err,
$errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT,     $ctx);
if (!$fp)
exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;
// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default'
);
// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);
// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
if (!$result)
echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
```

When I try to run the script, the terminal output is:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected token ":" in /Users/Desktop/simple push folder/simplepush.php on line 6`

What is the correct way to add the newly required header fields to this script?

Note: I've used the following [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/sending_push_notifications_using_command-line_tools?language=objc) to send a test notification to my testing advice.

Comment: You can't just copy and paste that example header request they show into PHP.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am still looking for some open source code I can take a look at. Do you know where I might be able to find it?

Comment: Remove line 3 to 17.

Comment: To be honest, i'm not sure with Apple's APN, but Googled this, it might help you: https://michael.wright.uk/sending-ios-push-notifications-with-php/

Comment: Thank you for that link @Bossman @luk2302 when I do that the terminal out put is `Connected to APNS
Message successfully delivered` but no message is received.

Comment: @luk2302 what about the newly required header fields, sir? It'd be great if there was a new tutorial out there.

Comment: the question never should contain real tokens because of security reasons. You can use text like `ExampleToken` instead of this.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

PHP said that your file have a syntax error. I believe it has nothing to do with request header.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The terminal says that the message is successfully delivered when I delete the headers, even though no message is received. I'm also not sure if they are correct to begin with. Again, it'd be great if Apple had an open source examples or some tutorials.

Comment: Have you seen request headers used like this before? I am completely new to this.